# using fopen() to read from a list of files, not the file itself

Tags: php, fopen

I'm hoping someone out there can tell me if I'm barking up the wrong tree to think that the following code might be modified slightly so that instead of opening one file, it opens a list of files that's contained in the first file.

Here's my current code:

```
$myFile = "atextfile.txt";
$v = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$data = fgets($v);
fclose($v);
$this->variable = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

It works fine, but to read multiple files I have to either cat all the small files into one massive one, or else repeat the above text for the 96 small files I'm trying to read.

What I'd like is to have a list of text files contained in the "atextfile.txt" file.  Another way might be if it can read all the "*.txt" files in a certain directory or something like that.  Then, by including or deleting the filename in this list, I'll be easily able to swap the order of files and/or change which files I'm including.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: *"repeat the above text"*...?! I hope you meant *loop*.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$myFile = file('atextfile.txt');

foreach($myFile as $file)
{
  if(file_exists($file))
  {
     $data[] = file_get_contents($file);
  }
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the directory, open all the files, capture all the data, do the single task.
You can append a function to the if statement to add addition conditions such as excluding filenames.

```
$data = null;
if ($handle = opendir('./path/to/files')) {
   while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." && substr($entry,-4) == '.txt') {
         $myFile = $entry;
         $v = fopen($myFile, 'r');
         $data .= fgets($v); // concatenate
         fclose($v);
      }
   }
   closedir($handle);
}
// capture the big string
$this->variable = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm aiming for but will the fgets($v) part add cr or linefeeds into the file?  I need one long string. For example, if it's "a" in one file and "bc" in the next, I need the final $data variable to be "abc" without anything else in there.  For some reason the above code is failing silently...not sure why but that might be the cause.